# Weak entity in ER design

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have a weak entity and it has an `id` as its primary key and also has another attribute (`author_id`) which has to refer to another entity's (`Author`'s) primary key.

So my question is this: can a weak entity have a composite key (`id, author_id`)?

Comment: What do you mean by "weak" entity??

Comment: weak entity is an entity that requires another entity for its own existance. for example, we have an entity called author and another entity called paper. here paper is a weak entity because without authors papers can not exist.

Comment: @user997248, not quite. A "weak entity" is one whose primary key includes a key for another entity. This is a concept in ER modelling but it is of little or no significance in relational modelling and for that reason it is often ignored.

Comment: @sqlvogel Do you mean that one should convert weak entities to strong entities by adding a surrogate key to them instead? kinda like [this](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=0CE8QFjAFOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fokaram.spsu.edu%2F~curri%2Fclasses%2F12%2Fspring-12%2FDB%2FStudyNotes%2FCh3-AdvancedER%2FAdvancedERModeling.pdf&ei=agbqUNEGi8u0Bp3hgNAG&usg=AFQjCNHmM6aKXEKroTZfzS9chHg-VyoIVQ&sig2=cGoUqjfNNCgbRTXJl965Bg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms) ? Are there any real use cases where one should prefer a weak entity explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

If Id is a key then (Id, Authorid) can't possibly be a key in the same table. No key is ever a subset of another because keys by definition should be irreducibly unique.

The answer to your question is yes. A weak entity may have a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

A weak entity is an entity with a primary key of which at least one its foreign keys are a part.  This is not possible with only one attribute. So

- if your primary key is really just `id`, you do not have a weak entity, but a strong entity;
- if your primary key is `id`, `whatever`, and `id` is already unique by itself, then `id` by itself should be your primary key;
- if your primary key is `id`, `whatever`, and neither `id` nor `whatever` are not unique by themselves, but `id`, `whatever` together are unique, then they are a legitimate primary key, and

  - if `id`, `whatever` are a foreign key together, you do not have a weak entity, but a subentity (the foreign key is an IS-A relationship);
  - if `id` and `whatever` are both foreign keys, you do not have a weak entity, but a relationship;
  - if one of `id` and `whatever` is a foreign key and the other is not, you have a weak entity.

All of these cases may occur. It depends on what you want to model and which information you have about it.